# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when running assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, lldb

I'm now learning GAS on my 64-bit macbook air.I write my first code .

```
# EXIT
    .section    segname, sectname
    .globl  _main
    .equ    maxCount, 0x114514
_main:
    movq $0x1, %rax
    retq
```

when debugging it using `lldb`

i found that

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100004000)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100004000 exit
exit`main:
->  0x100004000 <+0>: movq   $0x1, %rax
    0x100004007 <+7>: retq   
    0x100004008:      addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x10000400a:      addb   %al, (%rax)
Target 0: (exit) stopped.
```

I want to know what's wrong with my code.Does anyone have any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: You probably want to specify a well-known section name (like `.text` ?). What you gave may be interpreted as a data section ie non-executable.